# Flutter: show appbar only in some pages

Tags: flutter

I just want to have an appbar in some pages and no appbar in others, where should I place the appbar?

Currently the code looks something like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: OneContext().builder,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Home(),
        ),
  }
}

// this widget is needed to change dynamically the body widget maintaining the bottom navbar
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageWithAppbar(), // dynamically swapped with some PageWithoutAppbar()
      bottomNavigationBar: Nav.instance, // static bottom navbar
    );
  }
}

class PageWithAppbar extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(), // appbar showing incorrectly
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The appbar in PageWithAppbar appears underneath the status bar, and padding it with a SafeArea or Padding does not solve the problem as the padding is fixed (not device adaptive) and also it would appear black on top.

Wherease if I add an appbar to the Scaffold in App it shows up properly, but i don't want to because I only want the appbar in PageWithAppbar and not other pages.
How can I achieve the end result of having some pages with (properly adaptive) appbar and others without?

Comment: A page / view / sceen (however you wanna call it) should start with a `Scaffold` itself. Doing this will automatically enable you to add an `AppBar` only where you want it to

Comment: You have stacked 3 Scaffolds on top of one another. For pages that don't need the AppBar, you can leave out the Scaffold.

Comment: @daddygames as you correctly pointed out I removed the outermost Scaffold in App, however an appBar in Home does not show up at all, and adding it to PageWithAppbar still yields the same effect. Where should I put the appbar?

Comment: The Scaffold in Home is needed for its bottomNavigationBar property to apply to all pages

Comment: There are probably 1 million ways to handle this. One idea: Add something to `Home` that determines if the AppBar shows on a particular view. Then apply that to the `Scaffold` in the `Home` widget. Something like `Scaffold(appBar: _showAppBar ? MyAppBar() : null, body: MyPage());` You can use something like a [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) to update `_showAppBar` in the `Home` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE "HARD" WAY**

The most effective way of managing the AppBar is to place the `Scaffold` inside of every view instead of in a wrapper like you seem to be trying to do. Then you can control the app bar specifically in each view.

So with that solution, `App` would look something like this:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: OneContext().builder,
      home: Home(),
  }
}
```

...and `PageWithScaffold` would look something like this:

```
class PageWithAppbar extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(), 
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

...and `PageWithoutScaffold` would look something like this:

```
class PageWithoutAppbar extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

**SAMPLE APP USING CHANGENOTIFIER**

However, you do have options for using a `Scoffold` inside of a wrapper if you want. I have thrown together this example app (all one file) to show one possible way to do this using a [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html). The primary `App` registers a listener to the notifier. When something changes, a build is triggered for `App` and gives it the opportunity to show or hide the AppBar. I tried to comment the code in relevant places to explain what is happening.

Here is the example app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// this notifier will be used to trigger changes to the global scaffold
/// - used to show/hide the AppBar as desired
/// - used to display the current view (Widget)
/// - used to display the title in the AppBar
class AppNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool isDisposed = false;
  List<VoidCallback> _listeners = [];

  bool appBar = true;

  Widget currentView;

  String title = "Hello, World!";

  /// call this method to change which Widget is in view
  /// - [title] (default `Hello, World!`) provide a title to show in the AppBar
  /// - [includeAppBar] (default `false`) provide to show/hide the AppBar 
  void show(Widget view, {String title = "Hello, World!", bool includeAppBar = false}) {
    appBar = includeAppBar;
    currentView = view;
    title = title;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// call this to show the AppBar
  void showAppBar() {
    appBar = true;
    // the delay is to prevent build errors
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 25), () {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  /// call this to hide the AppBar
  void hideAppBar() {
    appBar = false;
    // the delay is to prevent build errors
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 25), () {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  @override
  void addListener(listener) {
    _listeners.add(listener);
    super.addListener(listener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _listeners.clear();
    isDisposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void removeListener(listener) {
    _listeners.remove(listener);
    super.removeListener(listener);
  }

}

// this notifer will be used to update the UI
AppNotifier notifier = new AppNotifier();

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {

  // this value is simply used to trigger state changes for the app
  int countChanges = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notifier.currentView = StartPage();
    notifier.addListener(() {
      // when something changes, trigger a rebuild
      setState(() {
        countChanges = countChanges+1;
      });
    });
  }

  // reset the view back to the StartPage
  void backToStart() {
    notifier.show(StartPage());
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: notifier.appBar // if `true` then we will show the AppBar
          ? AppBar(
            title: Text(notifier.title),
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: notifier.currentView is StartPage ? null : IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                // if on the StartPage, this icon will not appear
                // on other pages, this allows the user to return to the StartPage
                backToStart();
              },
            ),
          )
          : null,
        body: notifier.currentView
      )
    );
  }
  
}

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  StartPage({Key key});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _StatePageState();
}

class _StatePageState extends State<StartPage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!notifier.appBar) {
      // if the appBar is not showing, make it show
      notifier.showAppBar();
    }
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("Welcome to Hello World!"),
          Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child:OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // show the PageWithAppBar
                  notifier.show(PageWithAppBar(), title: "Page w/AppBar");
                }, 
                child: Text("Page With Scaffold")
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child:OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // show the PageWithoutAppBar
                  notifier.show(PageWithoutAppBar());
                }, 
                child: Text("Page Without Scaffold")
              )
            )
          ],)
        ],
      )
        
    );
  }
  
}

class PageWithAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  PageWithAppBar({Key key});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PageWithAppBarState();
}

class _PageWithAppBarState extends State<PageWithAppBar> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!notifier.appBar) {
      // tell the notifier to update the Scaffold and include the AppBar
      notifier.showAppBar();
    }
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Text("Hey! This page has an AppBar !")
    );
  }

}

class PageWithoutAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  PageWithoutAppBar({Key key});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PageWithoutAppBarState();
}

class _PageWithoutAppBarState extends State<PageWithoutAppBar> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (notifier.appBar) {
      // tell the notifier to update the Scaffold and dispose of the AppBar
      notifier.hideAppBar();
    }
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("Boo! This page does not have an AppBar ."),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              notifier.show(StartPage());
            }, 
            child: Text("Back to Start")
          )
        ],
      )
        
    );
  }

}
```

Hopefully this will give you some ideas on how to move forward with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, below is the output for the code above. The AppBar does show up and wrapping the scaffold with a SafeArea widget does start the AppBar after the status bar, not from the top edge. If this is correct for your requirement, I suggest revisiting your code structure or reinstall the App.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: OneContext().builder,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageWithAppbar(), // dynamically swapped with some PageWithoutAppbar()
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.done), label: "Ok"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.cancel), label: "Cancel"),
        ],
      ), // static bottom navbar
    );
  }
}


class PageWithAppbar extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page with AppBar"),
        ), // appbar showing incorrectly
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text("Test"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable that helps you to decide to create a page with or without appbar:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  late bool showAppBar;

  Home({required this.showAppBar}); 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: showAppBar ? PageWithAppbar() : PageWithoutAppbar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: Nav.instance,
    );
  }
}

class PageWithAppbar extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You create the `Home` like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: OneContext().builder,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(showAppBar: true/false),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```